# Value overlap on Android Spinner

Tags: android

Has anyone encountered such an issue before? The new value of the spinner overlaps the old one instead of replacing it.

[image: picture of graphical glitch]

This happens on application startup. Additionally, I've found that it happens on my tablet, but not on my phones.

**Relevant code:**

```
spinnerSearchField.setSelection(sharedPref.getInt(
        getString(R.string.lastChosenSpinnerValue), 0), false);

spinnerSearchField.setOnItemSelectedListener(
    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt(getString(R.string.lastChosenSpinnerValue),
                    spinnerSearchField.getSelectedItemPosition());
            editor.apply();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
```

**My layout file:**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/textViewSearchField"
            />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerSearchField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:entries="@array/arraySearchFields"
            />

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Are you sure use have only 1 Spinner there and not one covered by another one? Or you had Spinner covered by some TextView. Show us the code and xml layout

Comment: can you add code so that better understand.

Comment: @Stan, I've uploaded the relevant code. I cannot for the life of me figure out why this happens.

Comment: Try to load data to the spinner and init it in activity's code instead of xml's `android:entries="@array/arraySearchFields"`